# Excel, Load Sheet1 data to Sheet2, if Sheet1 rows increase Sheet2 rows should increase to show those data

Tags: excel, excel-365

I have Sheet1 connected to ODBC and loads data from mysql server.

Now I have Sheet2, it needs to populate all the values (rows & columns from Sheet1).

If Sheet1 refreshed from connection its rows will change, so now i want Sheet2 will have those refreshed rows as well.

Already tried:
I dont want to put like this `=Sheet1!C13`, because i dont know how many rows will Sheet1 have.

Comment: What is the Excel version you are working with? Please tag it as it could have an impact on the answer.

Comment: @Atmo, Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2303 Build 16.0.16227.20202) 64-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel 365, you can work with [spilled ranges](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531).

The base formula you have to type uses the `MAX(ROW(...))`/`OFFSET` trick to return a dynamic (spilled) range and would be something like (to type in `Sheet2!C1`):

```
=LET(MaxRow, MAX(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!C:C)),ROW(Sheet1!C:C))), OFFSET(Sheet1!C:C,0,0,MaxRow))
```

Note that you can work with more than just column C. Based on the above formula, we change the last part to be (using a 2-column contiguous range and the [`HSTACK` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hstack-function-98c4ab76-10fe-4b4f-8d5f-af1c125fe8c2) to add a third separate column):

```
LET(MaxRow, MAX(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!C:C)),ROW(Sheet1!C:C))), HSTACK(OFFSET(Sheet1!C:D,0,0,MaxRow), OFFSET(Sheet1!F:F,0,0,MaxRow)))
```

For formulas that use the resulting range, you will have to learn about the [spilled range operator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/spilled-range-operator-3dd5899f-bca2-4b9d-a172-3eae9ac22efd).

In `Sheet2:F1`, type:

```
="I test the spilled range operator with " & C1#
```

If you used the version of the formula returning 3 columns, you will see `C1#` "spills" on 3 columns too. This is easily solved by using the `INDEX` function like so (the 2 consecutive commas are not a mistake):

```
="I test the spilled range operator with " & INDEX(C1#,,1)
```